Order two anti-automorphism
I’m struggling with the notion of an order of an anti-automorphism. I saw it in a couple of texts and on wikipedia. Does it mean that it is not only an anti-automorphism but also an involution? For example, as I understand for a group the anti-automorphism $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is often said to be of order two. The same goes for matrix transpose.

Let $\phi$ be an automorphism. We say that $\phi$ has order $n$, if it has order $n$ as a group element in ${\rm Aut}(G)$, i.e., if $\phi^n=id$, but $\phi^k\neq id$ for all $k<n$. So order $2$ means a nontrivial involution. This terminology is also applied to anti-automorphisms.

@DietrichBurde Why are you posting answers in the comments?

@MartinBrandenburg I was not sure that this is an answer. But if the OP agrees, I will turn this into an answer.

@MartinBrandenburg makes perfect sense! thanks!!
